# Is Phone still usable after Google Find my device erase device

Tags: factory-reset, vivo, find-my-device

well, the question says it all. I was playing around with google find my device and messed up. The worse thing, I was using my father's phone and not mine.

**Result-**
After i used find-my-device - secure device, there's a screen lock on my father's phone which is long like abc1234. The phone is unlocking with it. But when I try to remove it from settings app, it is asking for a 4 digit numeric passcode. I have tried everything and the password can't be removed. Since my father uses his phone very often due to his work, he doesn't like any kind of password since its bothersome, time-consuming, frustrating and he doesn't have the best eyesight so he messes up with keyboard when without glasses.

**What I want to do-**
Since the phone can be unlocked and data can be accessed, I have backed up the data in my laptop and planning to reset it. Now, the OEM is locked and asks the 4 digit password to unlock and reset also wants that. So, My only options remains find my device - erase device.

**What i want to know-**
Since its not my but my father's phone, I want to be and have to be extra cautious. 
1 - Is there any kind of risk or anything i should keep in mind before resetting the device from find-my-device - erase device. 
2 - Will my father be able to use that phone normally after the reset like he used to earlier?? 
3 - **Will the screen lock be removed?? (most important)**

Comment: What you describe could be a bug, settings simply opens the wrong type of keyboard so you are unable to enter the password. Another possibility is the phone is managed e.g. a company that they have set-up the 4-digit PIN code. When performing a factory reset expect the worst - this means you have to set-up most of the apps from scratch with all their settings. Only apps from Google are mostly safe if cloud backup is enabled (exception: Google Authenticator app).

Comment: on factory reset device becomes FRP locked and can unlocked with google account. all data is gone. google drive backup can only restored with pin (you obviously don't have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so since no one was particularly answering, I took the risk and did it.

As for the answers for anyone who needs it in future -

1 - no that i found anything just make sure to backup your data.

2 - no problem found as well. for personalization and apps, everything was deleted, but i made a list beforehand of installed apps and their settings which took me a whole of 20-25 minutes to reinstall and set up.

3 - yes it was removed.

BTW for anyone wondering which phone it is, it's Vivo S1 Pro.